# Match a node without namespace in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given the following XSLT:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cm="http://api.example.com/schema">

    <template match="?">
        <element name="cm:Foo"><value-of select="?" /></element>
    </template>

</stylesheet>
```

And this XML:

```
<a>
  <b>cat</b>
</a>
```

How do I match the `a` node and select the value of the `b` node?

Notice that they do not have any namespace, and the default namespace in the stylesheet is already used, so simply `match="a"` and `select="b"` won't work (as far as I can see).

Comment: Have your tried it with `match="a"` and `select="b"` to see what happens? ;)

Comment: Yes, and that's why I asked ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default namespace of one XML document (your XSLT stylesheet) cannot influence in any way whether or not *another* XML document has a default namespace.

**Simply use**:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, remember that XPath always treats an unprefixed name as belonging to "no namespace".

Answer (score 1):

@pgfearo posted and deleted an answer which was correct. The solution was to set `xpath-default-namespace=""` on the `stylesheet`. So working xslt would be:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cm="http://api.example.com/schema"
    xpath-default-namespace="">

    <template match="a">
        <element name="cm:Foo"><value-of select="b" /></element>
    </template>

</stylesheet>
```

Without setting the `xpath-default-namespace` it doesn't match, which makes sense since there is no `a` or `b` node with the XSL Transform namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should do as the default namespace in the stylesheet code does not matter for XSLT patterns and XPath expressions. So `a` always means an element with local name `a` in no namespace, unless you use XSLT 2.0 and set `xpath-default-namespace="..."`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames. Your `xmlns="..."` does not matter.